# Dynamic change of angular expression not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular expression for ng-show attribute.

```
      <div style="height: 200px" class="collect-parcel" ng-show="{{shipment.type==1}}">
</div>
```

and in my controller

```
 $scope.shipment={type:2}
```

and in a click event I am changing the value like this

```
$scope.shipment.type = 1;
```

And when this click happens I expect the div to show, which is not happening for some unknown reason.

after the click event my rendered HTML is like this

```
  <div style="height: 200px" class="collect-parcel ng-hide" ng-show="true">

                    </div>
```

I Can't understand why the div is till not showing?

Comment: Have you tried without the curly braces in the expression? I believe those are meant to be used in inline html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be an *expression*:

```
ng-show="shipment.type == 1"
```

By the way, I recommend to keep developer console open all the time. In this case you would have notices an error message saying that `{{` is not a valid expression something.